# Drop rows if specific word is not present in a column where column have links and word need to be compare require splitting python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

here I am trying to analyze and practicing pandas.dataframe functions. Now I am trying to drop all rows which have not a specific word in the given column of links. [image]

You can see in the given image list of links. I need to drop the entire row if other than "Microsoft" appears in the link. In this case, I need to drop (4, 6, 7, 9, 13, 14, 16) rows.

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df_dictnew)
for j in df_dictnew['post_link']:
    i = j.split('/')[3]
    #print(i)
    if i != "Microsoft":
        df.drop(labels=None, axis=0, index=i, columns=None, level=None, inplace=True, errors='ignore')
```

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a much nicer solution - will only leave rows contain 'Microsoft':

```
df = df[df['post_link'].str.contains('Microsoft')]
```

Following your request for multiple search terms, here you go:

```
searchfor = ['MicrosoftLife', 'MicrosoftTeam']
df = df[df['post_link'].str.contains('|'.join(searchfor))]
```

Enjoy!

Third try (after clarification below):

```
# Create a column with the requested term (slicing after three '/')
df['term'] = df['post_link'].str.split('/', expand=True)[3]
# leave only relevant trems
searchfor = ['MicrosoftLife', 'MicrosoftTeam']
df = df[df['term'].str.contains('|'.join(searchfor))]
```

Comment: That's a great solution, need to know if there is another function in place of contains because I want to match exact string. In this case rows with "MicrosoftLife" and "MicrosoftTeam" left behind

Comment: Sorry to say, I am not asking for multiple search terms. I am asking for exact string match not contains or multiple matches. I only want rows with "Microsoft" nothing else. and I don't need to be hard coded.

Comment: Did I get it right this time? :-) Will leave rows where 'post_link' = 'Microsoft'

Comment: No... As you can see the format of link, i want to compare only the part before status for example ( twitter.com/Microsoft/status/ ) i just want to drop all those rows who have word other than "Microsoft". Basically, i will have a variable let's say account = "Microsoft" if any link have the same name of account variable keep that row, otherwise drop all others.

Comment: @AbdulAziz - I have edited the third solution above. Let me know if it is ok

Comment: As soon i get to my table, i will check it. I am sure this will work... Thanks is advance

Comment: @AbdulAziz - Please rate my answer :-) Thanks

Comment: Thank you so much. You are such a nice person and you worked smartly and intelligently to solve my problem. I really appreciate your effort and dedication.